# How do I create/obtain a permalink to user profile in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, profile, contacts, joomla2.5, permalinks

I have just migrated a lot of content from an old webpage to a 2.5 Joomla website. Almost every imported page contains a contact detail of one person from a 3-10 people pool.

I would like to define these contacts as Joomla contacts and just simply link to these profiles from every page.

How do I find or create a permalink to these user profiles?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a native Joomla way of doing this, but due to the frequent ugliness of Joomla urls, we use [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/) as an all-around link shortener on all of our sites.  It comes with a front end that users *are* able to create their own links, etc., but we just use the mechanism, and some of the other features on the admin site of things - the mechanism itself is quite straightforward and easy to use once you create one to see what needs to be in the database for it to do it's magic.